# Rails count values returned from pluck

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, count

I am building a rails application, and I need to create some charts.

I am running this query to retrieve the answers from the user:

```
quiz = Quiz.select("answer1").where(completed: true).pluck(:answer1)
```

And the query returns for me this: `[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]`

I want to count the values and group them like this: `{ 1 => 4, 2 => 1 }`

I have tried to use group by and count but it is not working, I could do this manually but I wanted to use just SQL to achieve this.

I remember to use group by and count using sql, but I am not sure how to do this using rails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `group('answer1')` as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)

```
Quiz.where(completed: true).group('answer1').count
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
Quiz.where(completed: true).group(:answer1).count(:answer1)
```